# Constant square difference partition point

Tags: geometry

Partition a line segment so that the difference between the square on the greater part and the square on the lesser part is constant.

[image: The point K splits AD into AK and KD, such that $AK^2 - KD^2 = AC^2$, AC is of fixed length]

In the figure, point K splits AD into AK and KD, such that $AK^2 - KD^2 = AC^2$, AC is of fixed length.

Can this be achieve by compass and straight edge?

Comment: Googling tells me that a square on a part refers to a square positioned in the plane with a given line segment as one of its sides. I'm still not sure what you mean by the difference between two of these squares being constant. (Constant with respect to what?)

Comment: If the length of the segment is $a$, and you are given $b$, are you asking to find $c$ so that $(a-c)^2-c^2=b?$

Comment: @RossMillikan, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the segment is a, and you are given b, we are asked to find c so that $(a−c)^2−c^2=b=a^2-2ac$  This gives $c=\frac{a^2-b}{2a},$ which is constructible.

Comment: That should be just $a^2 - 2ac$ without the $-2c^2$.

Comment: @RahulNarain:  Dropped a sign.  Thanks.  Fixed

Comment: Could any one demonstrate the construction process?

Comment: To construct $a^2$ draw a triangle with two sides $1$ and $a$, then construct a similar triangle with $a$ corresponding to $a$.  Then you can just subtract $b$ and divide by $a$ again using similar triangles.